# Related to problem 2.19 of convex optimization book by Stephen Boyd

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the solution of problem 2.19 of the book it is mentioned that $$\{x|x^TQx+2q^Tx\leq r,c^Tx+d>0\}$$ where $Q=A^TP^{-1}A-cc^T$, $q=b^TP^{-1}A+dc$ and $r=d^2-b^TP^{-1}b$. It is written that if $Q$ is positive definite then the above set is the intersection of an ellipsoid and the half space. The ellipsoid part comes from the condition $x^TQx+2q^Tx\leq r$ which can be equalently written as $$(x+Q^{-1}q)^TQ(x+Q^{-1}q)\leq d^2-b^TP^{-1}b+q^{T}Q^{-1}q$$ ($P$ is positive definite)This equality matches with the inequality described for ellipsoid if the right side of the inequality is positive. However, I do not know how to prove that the right side is always  positive. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what your question is? Are you confused by why the first inequality specifies an ellipsoid? The version of Boyd's book has 4 parts for problem 2.19, none of which involve a $Q$

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that the detail is in solution manual. For an ellipsoid the right hand side of my second inequality should be positive. But I do not know how to show this with given detail. So my question is how to show that the right side is a positive constant?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^TQx + 2q^Tx$ is just an upward facing paraboloid translated from the origin. In the case of $x\in \mathbf{R}^2$ you can visualize the first inequality as the intersection of the parabloid with a horizontal plane. If $r$ is positive you will get an ellipse, if r is 0 you get a single point, and if r is negative you just get the empty set. Is there a reason the set could not be empty? If you just make this a 1D ($x\in \mathbf{R}$) problem it seems clear $r$ can be negative

Comment: @Casey Thank you for your comment. I think your explanation is easier to understand. Now I know that $x^TQx$ is always greater than zero for any $x$ so if we can show that for the given information if $q^Tx$ is also always greater than zero then we can easily say that the solution set will be empty. (I do not have any problem with empty set, but I want to know how to show that when $r<0$ we will have empty set). Thank you.

Comment: Two small clarifications. $x^TQx$ _can_ be zero if $x = 0$ but no other $x$ (since $Q\in \mathbf{S}_{++}$). Second point, the $q^Tx$ doesn't really affect whether the set is empty, only the sign of $r$ will matter. Think of it in 1D $f(x) = ax^2 + bx$ where $a > 0$. The $bx$ term is just a shift left or right but the parabola still faces upwards and sits on the x-axis. The set of $x$ satisfying $ax^2 +bx < r$ being empty or not will depend only on whether $r$ is negative or not. Similar intuition for higher dimensions

Comment: @Casey suppose we have $f(x)=x^2+5x$ then we have a non-empty set for the case $x^2+5x\leq -2$ (I am considering one dimensional case). What am I missing?

Comment: Yes your example is correct. Your previous comment indicated you thought $q^Tx$ had to be positive for the set to be empty. I was just making the point that it need not. If $r$ is negative, the set will be empty (just as in your 1D example)

Comment: @casey "if r is negative the the set will be empty" why do you write this? When i have r=-2 in my example and the set is not empty for the one dimensional case.

Comment: you are totally right. Ignore that commentary on my part. I think the set can just be empty as we discussed above

Comment: Can you explain why you think $ Q = A^T W^{-1} A - c c^T $ is positive semidefinite? I don't even think that it has to be symmetric, because if $ W^{-1} $ is positive semidefinite, $ A^T W^{-1} A $ can still be non-symmetric.

Comment: Also can you explain why the last inequality is equivalent to the first?